# Getting Soundcloud 'liked' playlists with the developer API

Tags: javascript, api, set, soundcloud, playlist

I am trying to build an application that gets Soundcloud playlists, using these docs: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

What does work is the following:
SC.get("/users/mdbxz/playlists", { 'limit': l, 'offset': o } ...

However my problem here is '/playlists' does not return LIKED playlists, only the ones created by the users himself. So it just returns half the results.

After lots of Googleing I found it can be achieved using their live API (not the developer's!):
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/13082950/likes?limit=10&offset=0&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

My question here, do you know a way to get the same information using the developer api? ( connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js )

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working through another API URL as it seems the documented one simply does not provide the data. In case some stumbles upon this post; the code below fixed my dilemma:

```
SC.get(req.path,
    function(d)
    {
        if(d.id != 'null') {
            // New API
            var newApiUrl = "https://api.soundcloud.com/e1/";
            var newPath = "users/" + d.id + "/playlist_likes";
            callPath = newApiUrl + newPath + "?client_id=" + clientid;

            this.serviceBroker = SC.get(callPath, { 'limit': req.params.limit, 'offset': req.params.offset },
                function(d)
                {
                    //code
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```